# How to Convert 12Volt DC Automotive Battery Charger to 1.5V

Tags: resistors, dc, battery-charging, dc-dc-converter

I'm not an electrical engineer of any sort but was wondering if someone wouldn't mind sharing how I could choke a common AC to DC 12 Volt automotive battery charger down to 1.5V output while retaining the amperage that one of these battery chargers would normally output.

A friend suggested to place an inline resistor (on the positive lead I assume) in series to choke it down to 1.5V but I don't know what size resistor to install inline and if anyone wouldn't mind sharing the formula (and / or the component required in this case) I'd be most appreciative and thank you all in advance.

Thanks,
Stuart Kaufman

Comment: This is probably not a good idea.  A "battery charger" is not necessarily a power supply - it may take various shortcuts (pulsed current rather than steady) and may incorporate various "smarts" and algorithms which could be confused by additional circuitry.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. If you said what you really wanted instead of how you thought you might achieve it, there may be better suggestions. 1.5V we get ... but what current? what sort of protection? or what do you want to power with it?

Comment: Such a resistor would eat up 87.5% of all the power the charger delivers, which demands for a real big resistor which can cope with all the heat it produces. You had to constantly adjust the resistor to the resistance of the load, which is nearly impossible. 

Those resistors are rarely sold nowadays, because meanwhile there are many solutions not to waste all the energy. 

But to find a solution, that fits your problem, we need to know the real problem, not the half done solution.

Comment: What are you going to use the 1.5V for? Do you know around how much current you need at 1.5V? If you answer these questions, maybe we can redirect you to a solution that will work better for you.

Comment: Hi everyone, Thanks so much for such an awesome response. I'm wanting to step this automotive battery charger down to 1.5 because It's already something I have in the shop and I need 1.5V for electroplating motorcycle parts (I've learned a D battery doesn't cut it). I presume I can use as much amperage "as I can get" so I thought the battery charger would be a good candidate for this. BTW, I'm following this; http://www.finishing.com/faqs/howworks.html

Comment: Also, I'm strongly considering purchasing a dedicated benchtop powersupply because it seems like something cool and fun to have but if I can make an automotive battery charger do the trick with a jumper wire that has an inline resistor, that would be fine also (for now)

Comment: Additionally, I have experimented with adjustable walwart power supplys with poor results due to minimal (almost nonexistant) amperage output

Comment: I would go benchtop supply. Make sure you buy something that allows you to set a current limit. Basically, if you control the current, you will control the rate that the metal deposits on the object you are coating. Small surface area items can use low current. High surface area items will need proportionally higher currents to plate out at the same rate. Good luck!

Comment: @mkeith would you mind sharing with me what resistor may do the trick for this so I can run down to radioshack (yuk I know, i know) and get a resistor (with luck they might have it) so I can try out my homemade electroplating setup without waiting for a power supply? (Please remember I've been working on it with batteries and walwarts until this point)  I'll likely buy a powersupply soon but would also feel pretty good to have a custom 1.5 v jumper wire for now... I just don't know what value of resistor to use.

Comment: For this electroplating operation I'd rather use something such as the battery charger vs toting a specialized power supply out into that environment and If I knew the proper resistor to bring this down to 1.5V, I could expand upon it with my first ever frankenstein operation by adding a volt and ammeter to a board with leads that extend with aligator clips or such to connect to the anode and cathode. Something I could just connect the battery charger to, to connect to the parts to be plated would be great

Comment: EM Fields provided the equations necessary for the resistor approach. But this is a situation where you came to electronics experts asking for advice and now you are disregarding the advice they unanimously gave you. Just keep that in mind. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing electroplating, then you'll be more concerned with the current into the bath instead of the charger's output voltage, per se, so what you'll need to do will be to adjust the current into the bath until it gets to the current needed for the job.

The rub there is that since you can't adjust the charger's output voltage, you have to use some kind of a ballast to drop whatever the charger's voltage is down to whatever's needed to get the current into the tank to be what it has to be for the plating job.

If it turns out that you need 1.5 volts into the tank to get, say, 10 amperes through the work, then if your charger's putting out 14 volts the ballast will have to drop 12.5 volts (the charger's output voltage minus the voltage into the tank) at 10 amperes.

From Ohm's law, that ballast will have to have a resistance of:
$$ R = \frac{E}{I} = \frac{12.5V}{10A} = 1.25\text{ ohms} $$
and it'll have to dissipate:

$$P = IE = 12.5V\times10A = 125 \text{ watts} $$

That's a pretty hefty/pricey resistor, and the worst part is that if you need different currents for different jobs, you'll need more than just the one resistor, which is pretty nasty.

**UPDATE:**

From your comments, I understand your charger claims it can output either 6 volts at 2 amperes, 12 volts at 2 amperes, or 12 volts at 6 amperes.

That's not quite right, because the charger has to output a voltage higher than the battery voltage in order to charge it, so at full charge the 6 volt battery will be at somewhere around 7 volts and the 12 volt battery at around 14.

So with that in mind, along with your wish to provide 1.5 volts into the tank, If we model your setup it'll look something like the following, where\$ V1\$ is the output voltage from the charger, \$V2\$ is the input voltage to the tank, \$It\$ is the current into the tank, \$R1\$ is the resistance of the ballast, and \$R2\$ is the resistance of the tank (the load).

[image]

Now, using Ohm's law, we can do a couple of things, the first being to determine the tank's resistance if we know the voltage across it, \$V2\$, and the current through it, \$It\$.  Then, assuming \$V2\$ is 1.5 volts and \$It\$ is 2 amperes, can state:

$$ R2=\frac{V2}{It} = \frac{1.5V}{2A} = 0.75 \text{ ohms} $$

The second thing we can do is determine the value of \$R1\$ using Ohm's law as well.

Since in a series circuit the current is everywhere the same, the current through \$R1\$ will be \$It\$. The voltage across \$R1\$, however, will be the difference between the charger's output voltage, \$V1\$, and \$V2\$, so to get the value of \$R1\$ we write:

$$ R1 = \frac{V1 - V2}{It} = \frac {7V - 1.5V}{2A} = 2.75 \text{ ohms}  $$

Finally, to determine the power R1 will dissipate, we write:

$$ P = (V1 - V2)It = (7V - 1.5V) \times 2A = 11 \text { watts.}$$

Now, some caveats:

The first is that because the conductivity of the electrolyte can vary all over the place, the assumption that 1.5 volts across the bath will always be OK is a dangerous one.  What should be done is that the current through the bath be monitored and the voltage varied in order to maintain the current at the desired point.

The second is to assume **anything** about the charger. It would be a very good idea to get ahold of a schematic and find out what's going on in there before you spend a lot of money on resistors or any kind of current-limiting scheme.

The third is to always calculate the ballasts's dissipation, determine its temperature rise, and pay attention to the manufacturers' derating curves.

The fourth is to realize that while the procedures I've shown you will work in any situation, the numerical values I used were only examples.  That is, you should measure everything in **your** system in order to get meaningful data out.

Comment: Hi @EM Fields. I'm not sure what amperage is necessary or sufficient, I' just learned that voltages higher than 1.5V are not desirable so I was thinking I'd just choke down the battery charger which also has a 6V 2A setting I could work off of if I knew how to step it down to 1.5V I'd just use it before resorting to this which I would only be able to use for plating at this time: http://www.ebay.com/itm/30V-5A-Precision-Variable-Adjustable-Digital-DC-Power-Supply-W-Clip-Cable-110V/380937855913 (which I would like to have also)

Comment: If I bought the powersupply linked above. I'd set it at 1.5V and twist the Amperage knob as far to the right as it goes and stand back with safety glasses on, then work backwards from there until I establish the ideal amperage for different parts (which further cements the need for the adjustable power supply) but I'd really like to have a battery charger adapter for doing  this as well

Comment: @Stuart:Part 1.) You don't understand. If you need, say,  2 amperes through the bath to get the plating done properly, then what you need to do is vary the voltage into the bath **with no regard as to what the actual voltage is** until  the current into the bath is 2 amperes.

Comment: @Stuart: Part 2.) For example, if the supply you mentioned can supply a constant current  and you wanted 2 amperes through the bath, then what you'd do would be to set the current and voltage controls both to zero, connect the supply outputs to the anode and the cathode, crank the voltage control to max, and then adjust the current control until you got 2 amperes into the load.  That way, no matter what the bath resistance looked like, the supply would automatically adjust its output voltage in order to make sure that it was always outputting 2 amperes.

Comment: @Stuart: How much current is available from the 12V side of the charger and what's the maximum current you'd like to be  able to push through the tank?

Comment: Hi @EM Fields, Thanks so much for all the help. I'm not trying to be argumentative, I'm just trying to understand everything but In regards to you saying: "with no regard as to what the actual voltage is" I can't say I disagree because I'm not as knowledgable as yourself in electrons but I would like to ask  you to look at the first answer here: http://www.finishing.com/336/41.shtml

I initially started with 1D battery and since 1 D battery semi worked I figured 2 (3v) would be better but as it turns out, 3V is not better in practice as explained in article above so I moved to walwarts

Comment: Walwarts did nothing due to a later learned lack of amperage output from these after ordering an "adjustable" walwart from the www and attempting to use it with poor results which I later found an explanation for here: https://learn.adafruit.com/power-supplies/transformer-based-ac-slash-dc-converters

Comment: The available and maximum output from the automotive battery charger (according to the label anyways) is:
12V 2A, 12V 6A and 6V 2A. which makes it seem ideal for making a "jumper" wire with a resistor I can connect direct to the battery charger to reduce it to 1.5V and have a selection of 2 or 6 Amps into the bath.

Comment: Also, making this work from a small automotive battery charger (like what everyone in the automotive / motorcycle industry has) would enable me to share how to do this with other DIY'ers without the need for an expensive or specialized power supply. There are YouTube videos detailing this process with batteries which are full of BS as doing this with a battery never achieves satisfactory results even on a small fastener so I'm trying to devise something better than a battery, yet not needing of a specialized power supply

Comment: I'd like to add the following excerpt from previously linked article above:
"But if you try to plate at too high a rate (and 6V is too high!), there will not always be positively zinc ions available at the cathode to join up with the extra electrons your power pack has pumped there ... so the electrons will steel H+ from the water, converting it to H2 gas bubbles"

Comment: I Thank you immensely for your thorough and well explained (yet still over my head) explanation. I AM going to be working off of the examples and equations you provided starting with an LM317 of which I was going to supply with the battery charger and limit with a pot. (was going to be a 50Ohm resistor until I saw your mention of monitoring and adjusting the voltage) and I thank you many times over for your assistance. (Note: I learned through the www that a LM317 will only allow 1.5A draw but I'm gonna start with an LM317 before ordering the aforementioned power supply)

Comment: And I will be revisiting, studying and learning from your most awesome response and illustration for quite some time. Thank You

Comment: Update: Since I was unable to edit my comment due to 5Min rule, I wanted to specify that I was going to try a LM317 as my "Ballast" in the above illustration that @EM Fields so kindly provided. UNLESS someone advises against doing so, in which case I will  be reduced to the only option of ordering a dedicated power supply

Comment: I would like to follow up this thread with a conclusion. Due to radio shack's disappointing selection I have abandoned the LM317 idea and am now going to order the specialized power supply unit I previously linked to. I essentially took the long way around and wish I would had ordered that long ago but I am glad I learned alot about voltage and amperage along the way and I thank you all for the insight and discussion about this  matter. Thanks.
Stuart

Comment: @Stuart: I just finished watching, yesterday,  a Ken Burns film series about the Roosevelts, and I was quite moved by the openness,  kindness,  and courtesy exhibited by non-enemies  in written communications during that era.  You seem to have inherited that spirit, so my hat's off to you.